# Product page count and record count issue on listing page

Tags: product, magento-2.2.5, toolbar

Unable to change the record on listing page it shows static number for all listing page as shown in the image

[image]

It display 10000 for all listing page using `$this->_productCollection()->getSize()` though the count greater than 10000